# Kivy/PyMongo: Using 'enter' key in TextInput to feed entered note into database

Tags: python, kivy, pymongo

I am trying to make a part of an app where basically the person gets to leave small one-line reminders for themselves. I want to make sure that when the person presses 'enter', the note gets saved into the database.

This is my code in main.py:

```
class Reminders(Screen):
    collection = db['Notes']
    note_text = TextInput()
    note_num = collection.count_documents({})

    def add_note(self):
        self.note_text = TextInput(text='Note', size_hint=(0.2, 0.25), multiline=False, on_text_validate=self.keyboard_down)
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(self.note_text)

    def keyboard_down(self, **kwargs):
        entry = {'_id': (self.note_num + 1), 'Note': self.note_text.text}
        self.collection.insert_one(entry)
```

my.kv:

```
  FloatLayout:
    Label:
        text: "Reminders"
        color: (0, 0.702, 0, 1)
        font_size: 50
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'top': 1}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2

    Button:
        text: 'Add'
        size_hint: 0.07, 0.07
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.78,'top': 0.94}
        on_release: root.add_note()

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 0.96, 0.6
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.02, 'top': 0.7}
        StackLayout:
            id: layout
            orientation: 'tb-lr'
```

(These are all just little snippets of the code. The kv code is under the tag < Reminder >)

I am getting a Type Error >TypeError: keyboard_down() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

(The error occurs when I actually press enter).
[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def keyboard_down(self, **kwargs):
```

Your function definition takes one positional argument, which you have named `self`. The error tells you that it's being passed two positional arguments. You must change your definition to match how it's called, e.g.

```
def keyboard_down(self, _, **kwargs):
```